# Using GMP in compile-time calculation

Tags: c++, c++11, gmp

I'm trying to use GMP with C++11, but apparently it's not allowed to use mpz_class in constexpr functions because mpz_class is not a literal type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

constexpr mpz_class factorial(mpz_class n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

int main()
{
    cout << factorial(20);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just don´t make it constexpr.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  GMP is a C library and therefore has no possibility of supporting C++ compile-time `constexpr` computation.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in checking out the Boost.Multiprecision (BMP) library:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

It has some support for `constexpr`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/lits.html

Note that the `constexpr` support is limited to the `cpp_int` backend (BMP's version of arbitrary-precision integers). BMP does provide a backend that wraps GMP types though, so I suppose in your case you could do the `constexpr` calculation using `cpp_int` and then convert to GMP at runtime.